# Change SVG Path Embedded into button

Tags: css, svg

I can change the SVG Path very easily but when i insert it in button the css:hover is not working in firefox. Please check [**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vww63s0s/)

**CSS:**

```css
#Fill-1 {
  fill: red;
}
#Fill-1:hover {
  fill: black;
}
```

Comment: You mean the `:hover` is not working?

Comment: I am on Chrome and the fill does change on hover.

Comment: Yea , it`s working in chrome but not working in fire fox:(

Answer (score 1):

The button swallows the mouse events so the SVG never gets them. You can make hover work by targetting the hover to the button though. You'll need to ensure that the item you're targetting does not have an inline fill attribute so the button's fill can set it.

```
button {
     fill:red;
 }
button:hover {
     fill:black;
 }
```

[like so](http://jsfiddle.net/vww63s0s/2/)

There is a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003) that tracks this

Answer (score 0):

The button class doesn't seem to be messing anything up. You should try changing the css to point to Button instead of #Fill-1 and #Fill-2.  They aren't needed.

```
button {fill:red}
button:hover {fill:black}
```